# Excel conditional formatting on similar cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

We have a list of computers in an excel table, a few thousand.  Most are named in the format of <3digit office code> - .  For example, NYC-1234567.  Sometimes, when machines get re-imaged, the techs will add a few digits to the end, since they don't want to delete the machine from the domain (or don't have the rights), so for example, NYC-1234567b or NYC-1234567-2

We also have some machines that might have been moved to another office, for example, if moved to LA, it might become LAX-1234567.

I need to "get rid" of duplicates in our spreadsheet to clean up licensing.  I have played a bit with conditional formatting.  I see I can set a formula for cell A2 conditional formatting of =COUNTIF(A:A,A2)>1 which will trigger on any duplicates.  But how would I compare just the serial numbers, characters 4-11?  I am at a bit of a loss.  I'm not much of an Excel person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new column and use this formula:

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(A1; (LEN(A1) - FIND("-"; A1))); 7)
```

After that just use the conditional formating on that column to find duplicates.

Comment: That is awesome, thank you.  I did have one problem, excel 2007 didn't like the semicolons, and I had to change it to comma's if someone else is going to try this.